# Get current screen orientation

Tags: x11

Using [`xrandr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr), I can rotate my screen with

```
xrandr -o inverted
```

and back again with

```
xrandr -o normal
```

Is there also a way to *read* the current screen rotation? Preferably using `xrandr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## With `xrandr --query --verbose`

Using the `--query` and `--verbose` options, `xrandr` will print all kinds of information about your screens.

Assuming the screen you're interested in is `LVDS-1` (you can get names by calling `xrandr`), this will produce a line containing its current screen rotation:

```
xrandr --query --verbose | grep "LVDS-1"
```

You can see the current orientation `normal` as the sixth field:

> LVDS-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (0x4a) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 277mm x 156mm

We can use [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) to extract the screen orientation from the line:

```
xrandr --query --verbose | grep "LVDS-1" | cut -d ' ' -f 6
```

Comment: Not precise enough. --verbose gives i.e: `HDMI2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x46) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 470mm x 260mm` and if you go with `cut -d ' ' -f 6` it will incorrectly give you `(normal` instead of `normal` as it would by using `-f 5`. To recap: it might fail just because the display is not *"primary"* and the split index is therefore off-by-one.

Comment: So in my case, to ignore the output being *"primary "* or not I used: `xrandr -q --verbose | grep HDMI2 | sed 's/primary //' | awk '{print $5}'`